# Only print a footnote of a acronym once per page in the footnotes.- LaTeX

Tags: latex, acronym

I want the acronym package to only print a footnote, if its not already printed on that specific page. And give the \acf{XX} the same number in the text.
It should look like this:

```
Text
The USA¹ are country as well as the UAE², but the USA¹ are bigger.

___________________
1 United States of America, 2 United Arabic Emirates

Next page:

The UAE¹ are still a country.

___________________
1 United Arabic Emirates
```

But it looks like this:

```
Text
The USA¹ are country as well as the UAE², but the USA³ are bigger.

___________________
1 United States of America, 2 United Arabic Emirates, 3 United States of America

Next page:

The UAE¹ are still a country.

___________________
1 United Arabic Emirates
```

My code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[footnote]{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage[1]{footnote} 



\begin{document}

\section*{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[ECU]
\acro{USA}{United States of America}
\acro{UAE}{United Arabic Emirates}
%[...]
\end{acronym}
\newpage

\section{Text}
The \acf{USA} are a country as well as the \acf{UAE}, but the \acf{USA} are bigger.
\newpage
The \acf{USA} are still a country.
\end{document}
```

I tried a lot but couldnt find out a Solution on my own - Maby someone here is better in LaTeX as me and could provide me some help.

Greetings
Tristan.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `\acf` you request a "full acronym", so you explicitly override what the package would normally do. If you use `\af` instead, you'll only get the footnote the first time.

As for "first time¨: the acronym package tracks whether it has spelled out the acronym already. You can reset this counter with `\acresetall`. This is independent of pages. In your example with the forced page break you could simply add `\acresetall` after `\newpage`. In larger documents you could add it to each `\section` or `\chapter`, or have it [done automatically with the `etoolbox` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/acronym-package-full-name-after-each-section-chapter) or look into [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380966/insert-text-after-page-break-in-paragraph) to hook it into a page break.